# Pulling too much power from a 9V battery?

Tags: batteries

I found something that makes 9V go to 15V 3A and before I make the project is it bad to do that and will it kill my 9V batteries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is **way** too much. [Typical battery life table](http://www.techlib.com/reference/batteries.html) shows 500 mAh capacity. That means 0.5 A for 1 hour. Or 3 A for 10 minutes. That's not even counting on somehow going up to 15 V, and that is also assuming the battery doesn't catch on fire from such a fast discharge.

So the basic answer is: Don't even try it.

You need a much larger power source, or a design that requires a lot less power.

Comment: thank you but I am stepping up the voltage to 15V not pulling 15V

Comment: As I understand it, you are trying to pull 15V @ 3A. That is 45 W. Assuming you have a totally lossless conversion (impossible, but I'll assume you get close), that is simply too much power to pull from a 9V battery. I was actually being generous by calculating at 9V x 3A = 27W.

Comment: What if I use what's called a jouel thief?  it stores energy and then dumps it at what you need and it happens so fast that it's like its uninterrupted. will it still blow shrapnel all over my wear house? (its my pantry lol) rip food

Comment: Doesn't sound too good. What are you actually trying to do with the 15v 3a?

Comment: power a 15V 3a Peltier module to make a slurpee machine! yum :P

Comment: for that you'll need a much larger battery.

Comment: okay thank you I will think of manassehkatz and Jasen when I enjoy my slurpeies yum :)

Comment: For a motor load (for crushing ice & mixing), there is relatively little optimization that can be done - it is simply a large load. Small batteries (AA, AA, C, D, 9V) really don't work well for those types of applications. Your best bet would be either a relatively large rechargeable battery (i.e., enough to make a couple of slurpees between charges, then plug it in until the next time) or more typically use a wired (mains - 120V or 240V depending on your area) machine, which can easily draw even 100s of watts at a time without a problem.

Comment: this is the time I want to break the website because I cant ask for shop recommendations but, will a 15V 3A power supply work?

Comment: Yes. That's what you want - a plugin power supply rated to match the load.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: yes

A typical high-ish performance lithium pp3 battery (like [this](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/la522.pdf)) is rated for 1A continuous discharge. At maximum load, you would be pulling at least 15V/9V * 3A = 5A from it. Even if the PP3 battery voltage didn't sag to like 3V (and it will), youll get a battery life on the order of about 5 minutes.

If you add the voltage sag due to internal resistance to this equation, what will happen is that your system will simply stop working. Your battery will also likely heat up a lot, possibly causing a fire.

Comment: just to clarify I'm not pulling 15V 3A I'm using a power step-up

Comment: It's a voltage step-up. it doesn't increase the power.